# Expand rational fractional expression in power series $\frac{k^2}{(k^2+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}}$

Tags: power-series, rational-functions

Expression as showed in the title and n can be take arbitrary natural numbers, 0,1,2,....
How to expand it in powers of k and what coefficient of $k^m$ is?
Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{coefficient of $x^m$ in }\frac{k^2}{\left(k^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}}=\text{coefficient of $x^{m-2}$ in }\left(k^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-(n+2)}=\begin{cases}2^{n+2+(m-2)/2}\;^{-(n+2)}{\rm C}_{(m-2)/2}&\text{m%2==0}\\0&\text{m%2!=0}\end{cases}$$
Because $$(1+x)^{-n}=\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}\;^{-n}{\rm C}_{\nu}x^{\nu}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But what if it is as a part of integrand? I'd like to compute the integral with following form $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{(k^2+\frac{1}{2})^{n+2}} J^2_{\ell}(k^2) J_{2s+1}(\tau k)dk$, whose integrand converge.

Comment: But if expand the rational fractional expression, the integrand of $\int_{0}^{\infty} k^m J^2_{\ell}(k^2)J_{2s+1}(\tau k)dk$ does not converge completely.

Comment: @Peng sorry i have no idea about bessel functions

Comment: @ ADG Thank you for your solution.